# How do I create a mock service in an Android test?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I have a service (lets call it A) and it relies on services B and C.

I want to unit test A, so I would ideally like to capture any intents emitted from the service that would start B or C and replace the results with a mock instance of the services. However, Android's test setup doesn't seem to have an obvious way of implementing this.

Espresso intents seems to be the nearest to this but it doesn't seem to cover binding to a service. Does anyone know how to do this?

A is getting a binder to B and C via code like...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
context.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

...

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        B.BinderStub bInstance = (B.BinderStub) service;
    }
...
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I want A to work correctly but have the instance of B be a mock.

Comment: Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it, but I think you can do what you want using `PowerMock`

```
B myMock = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().doReturn(myMock)
```

### References

- PowerMock introduction: https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock#mocking
- whenNew documentation: https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.5/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew-java.lang.Class-

Comment: Doesn't PowerMock need a `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`? In order to have services and binding, a test class needs to have `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`. :-(

Comment: It seems that this is possible using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(AndroidJUnit4.class)` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219843/unable-to-mock-static-methods-in-instrumentation-tests/42762405). But it doesn't seem to work on tests using the Espresso framework unfortunately.

Comment: At least for me, I cannot get it to work with PowerMock *at all*: As soon as I add the `androidTestImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2'` dependency, I get `Program type already present: org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithExpectedArguments` error when trying to run an android test.